# find words in a text in c++

Tags: c++, string, file, parsing

Suppose there is a text file containing these in the fallowing style:

```
      name: natalie, sarah
      surname: parker
      age: 24
      contry: dubai
```

I want to get `natalie` and `sarah` as the name, `parker` as the surname and so on. After this, somewhere in my code I need variables name, surname, age (as natalie, sarah, parker, 24 etc..).

I think, first I need to read file and store it in an array and than parse it with using delimiters which are : " "(space) or ":" in order to parse `<surname: parker>` this one, and also use "," comma as a delimiter in order to parse `<natalie, sarah>`.

I could store the text in an array or use getline(textfile, size) for getting the lines, because I need exactly one line in each time. Which is the most suitable do you think? And how we can do the parsing?

Comment: Why dont you use a class or structure for storing the details

Comment: Looks like good ideas. Try them out and see how far you get. Then come back and ask about any specific problems you run into (if any).

Comment: Unless you have performance or size constraints you should use a well know format such as xml or a well established database like sql

Comment: I do not know which is the most efficient one

Comment: You don't have to be amazingly efficient unless you are Facebook with a billion names. Anything will work for a reasonable data size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of something like this (simplified; no error checking or optimization and such; this is untested, but should work):

```
std::ifstream file(myfile);
std::string line;

std::map<const std::string, std::string> dataset;

while (file >> line) {
    size_t var_start = line.find_first_not_of(" \t"); // get beginning of the variable name
    size_t var_end = line.find_first_of(":"); // get the end of the variable name
    if (var_start == std::string::npos || var_end == std::string::npos) // any not found?
        continue; // skip this line
    std::string var_name = line.substr(var_start, var_end - var_start); // get the variable name
    std::string var_value = line.substr(var_end + 1); // get the variable content

    // now do something, e.g. safe it
    dataset[var_name] = var_value;
}
```

Comment: when I need to use dataset[var_name] how do I call it?

Comment: like dataset[0] or dataset[name]?

Comment: It's a map, the key is a `std::string`, so you'd use `dataset["name"]` for example, but that's really up to you (you could just compare `var_name` to literals and assign different variables).

Comment: how can I handle the "," part? name: natalia, sarah and I should get natalia and sarah seperately, how can I do that?

Comment: The same way, look for the position of the separator (e.g. using `find_first_of()`), then split it as I did above (e.g. using `substr()`).

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the target. I just have a little bit suggestions:

- Use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to store data from file
- Use while loop to get each line from file, use [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c) or [boost::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html) the string by `:` to get key and value and store them in map.

Comment: Just to add, I'd also look into tokenizing: it'll come in handy for things like "name: natalie, sarah, ..., ...,".

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to solver it easier.
Pattern like this :
"name:([\w,]+)surname(\w+)"